# SQL Server CE 3.0 - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database file (`.sdf`) of version 3.0 which is corrupted. I am trying to repair this file.

Using SQL Server CE 3.1 reference for `System.Data.SqlServerCe`, when I try to Repair/Compact the file with engine.Repair or engine.compact, it gives error message

> *AccessViolationException - Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Have anybody faced similar issue and have a solution ?

Comment: Make sure to use the latest build of the 3.0/3.1 engine: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2009/07/sql-server-2005-compact-edition.html